# vis.js - Update "navigationButtons" CSS so the buttons are at the top of he canvas

Tags: css, vis.js

I am using vis.js and would like to align the buttons displayed when using the "navigationButtons" option to the top of the canvas. 
I understand this is done using CSS, I was wondering if anyone had any examples?

Thank you in advance,

Anadi.

Comment: Can you post the generated code? or create a fiddle example?

Comment: Here is a link to the CSS.
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/web.imedialibrarysports.com/css/vis.css

The relevant styles are:
vis-button vis-up
vis-button vis-down
vis-button vis-left
vis-button vis-right
vis-button vis-zoomIn
vis-button vis-zoomOut
vis-button vis-zoomExtends

Comment: If my answer is correct please mark as correct, or if you found a better solution, please post it so we all can share and learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preferable some HTML would be nice to work with. However you mention you'd like to update the "alignment" of the buttons. Therefore I would assume the "bottom:" and "right:" attributes is what you are looking for. However, since you want the alignment towards the top, you may want to use the "top:" attribute instead of "bottom:" and "left:" instead of "right:"...

E.g... The following should align these 4 buttons horizontally across the top... update the "left:" attribute to suit your preferred gutter width.

```
div.vis-network div.vis-navigation div.vis-button.vis-up {
    background-image: url("...png");
    top:10px;
    left:50px;
}
div.vis-network div.vis-navigation div.vis-button.vis-down {
    background-image: url("...png");
    top:10px;
    left:100px;
}
div.vis-network div.vis-navigation div.vis-button.vis-left {
    background-image: url("...png");
    top:10px;
    left:150px;
}
div.vis-network div.vis-navigation div.vis-button.vis-right {
    background-image: url("...png");
    top:10px;
    left:200px;
}
```